# How to prove the dual of a norm

Tags: convex-optimization

I am studying convex optimization and saw the following. How do I prove it ? I would use what i learnt - lagrangian multipliers to formulate the dual but I don't know how to do it. There are no constraints on the original function.

And every website I go to just shows this property without proving it.

[image]

Comment: It's not a property, it's a definition...

Comment: so there is no way to prove it ?

Comment: @kong by definition, definitions need not to be proved...

Comment: Turning the story differently: assume you would like to prove the inequality, what is $\|x\|_*$ ?

Comment: @kong: There is nothing to prove. You might as well try to prove the colour blue.

Comment: thank you all !

Comment: A more suitable question is whether this definition coincides with the definition of a convex conjugate. In other words: does $\sup_x \{z^Tx - ||x||\} = \sup_x \{z^Tx \mid ||x|| \leq 1\}$ hold?

Comment: Acutally—it is by no means obvious that the dual definition produces a *norm*. That would be worth proving.